# Is this function safe?

Tags: php, security

Paying someone to do a security job and they say this is secure, so wanted to check with you guys:

```
function mysql_prep( $value ) {
  $magic_quotes_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
  $new_enough_php = function_exists( "mysql_real_escape_string" ); 
  // i.e. PHP >= v4.3.0
  if( $new_enough_php ) { // PHP v4.3.0 or higher
    // undo any magic quote effects so mysql_real_escape_string can do the work
    if( $magic_quotes_active ) { $value = stripslashes( $value ); }
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string( $value );
  } else { // before PHP v4.3.0
    // if magic quotes aren't already on then add slashes manually
    if( !$magic_quotes_active ) { $value = addslashes( $value ); }
    // if magic quotes are active, then the slashes already exist
  }
  return $value;
}
```

Comment: Why check for PHP 4.3.0 - It was released in 2002-12-27

Comment: This code is not safe against attacks exploiting multibyte characters when using a different encoding for DB than your script

Answer (score 4):

To be honest... I would recommend you to go to the next level, Skip mysql_ library, go for a Database Abstraction Layer, like PDO and use prepared statements. You will have a lot of new features to use, your life will be simpler, faster, better, stronger.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Yes, the function above are secure.  But could be modified, I highly doubt you have a version less 5. But it is old, indeed..

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me - Just make sure they are using single quotes around their values in SQL queries, because `mysql_real_escape_string` alone isn't enough.

For example instead of:

```
"SELECT Forename FROM users WHERE userID = $user_id;"
```

It should be:

```
"SELECT Forename FROM users WHERE userID = '$user_id';"
```

That is assuming `$user_id` has been escaped using that function.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [MySQLi](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php) which gives you Prepared Statements and removes the need to manually escape Strings.

Also, if you need to execute the same query multiple times (with different arguments), preparing a statement is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

This function mixes two different concerns:

- Normalizing the *input values* in an environment where magic quotes can't be controlled
- Escaping *sql parameters*

The undoing of input escaping should be done in a single function at the beginning of your code. Or if you control the environment just disable magic quotes.

The SQL escaping should happen where the query is formed. Or even better use prepared statements or a similar mechanism, where you don't need to manually escape parameters at all.

---

This mixing of concerns leads to strange effects:

If you have user created data that comes from the request, and untrusted data from other sources you need to treat them differently. Else you can a security hole on systems with magic quotes enabled.